# Apigee policy mediation - assign message / extract variables

Tags: javascript, apigee

I am exposing a JSON over REST interface via Apigee Edge.

Externally, the API consumers will see the following API Spec:

i.e. creating a customer.

```
POST /customers?api_key=ABC123
{
   "name": "John",
   "surname": "Smith"
}
```

I have applied the following policies:
1. Verify API Key
2. Remove API Key

I was wondering how may I be able to use extract / assign message policy to achieve the following "reconstructed" request payload when calling my downstream system.

```
POST /downstream-customer-service
{
   "correlationId": "<generated guid>",
   "data": {
      "name": "John",
      "surname": "Smith"      
   }
}
```

So, I need to:
1. Move the original request body, and add it to a "data" element
2. Generate a GUID and assign it to the "correlationId"

I assume I also need a javascript policy? or could this be achieved within only a javascript policy?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used a JavaScript policy, and applied it to Target Endpoint PreFlow:

```
var This = (function() {
    self.generateUUID = function(a) {
        // UUID4 generation: https://gist.github.com/jed/982883
        return a?(a^Math.random()*16>>a/4).toString(16):([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g,self.generateUUID);
    },
    self.modifyPayload = function(data, generateCorrelationId) {
        var newPayload = {
            "data": data
        };

        if(generateCorrelationId)
            newPayload["correlationId"] = self.generateUUID();

        return newPayload; 
    }
    return self;
})();

var modifiedData = This.modifyPayload(context.targetRequest.body.asJSON);
context.setVariable("context.targetRequest.body", modifiedData);
```